# How can i use c++ module in vscode with xmake(or cmake)?

Tags: c++, cmake, c++20, xmake

my project can be compiled with clang-17 and xmake.I used Clion to code before.in vscode,I tried clangd plugin(has enabled experimental feature),and pass compile_commands to it,but it still report "module file dont found" error.then I tried vscode cpptools plugin,it also cannot find module file,too.what should I do to fix it?I cannot find any right guide on the internet

i tried updating my clangd to newest version and use cpptools's pre-release version,but nothing happen.

i hope to use cpp20 module in vscode.